# ¿Cómo crear dinámicamente variables dentro de un while?

Tags: php

Hago una consulta MySQL (bucle `while`) para saber las fotos de un producto y cada nombre de foto lo quiero guardar en una variable, no imprimirlo y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Éste es mi código:

```
$consulta2 = mysql_query("select nombre, alt from fotos where id_producto='$id' ");
$filas2 = mysql_fetch_array($consulta2);
while($filas2 = mysql_fetch_array($consulta2)){
    echo $filas2['nombre'];
    echo $filas2['alt'];
}
```

En vez de `echo`, quiero que mientras dure el bucle se guarden los resultados en variables distintas: la primera foto en `$foto1`, la segunda en `$foto2` y así todas. Cada foto en una variable distinta a la variable de la foto anterior, y lo mismo con los `alt`.

Comment: ¿Qué tal un array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Puedes crear dinámicamente variables con la sgte sintaxis:

```
${nombre-de-variable}
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$consulta2 = mysql_query("select nombre, alt from fotos where id_producto='$id' ");
$filas2 = mysql_fetch_array($consulta2);

$i = 0;
while($filas2 = mysql_fetch_array($consulta2)) {
     $i++;
     ${"foto" . $i} = $filas2['nombre'];
     ${"alt" . $i} = $filas2['alt'];
}
```

Alternativamente también podrías crear dos arrays donde puedes ir almacenando los nombres y los alt

```
$consulta2 = mysql_query("select nombre, alt from fotos where id_producto='$id' ");
$filas2 = mysql_fetch_array($consulta2);

$i = 0;
$fotos = [];
$alts = [];
while($filas2 = mysql_fetch_array($consulta2)) {
     $i++;
     $fotos[$i] = $filas2['nombre'];
     $alts[$i] = $filas2['alt'];
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu  ayuda, me ha servido.Funciona perfecto

Comment: Otra alternativa: un solo array compuesto por hash tables (arrays asociativos) donde cada hash table contiene la información de foto y alt.

Comment: @kato si la respuesta te ha servido podrías marcarla como aceptada y/o votarla positivamente.

Answer (score 1):

puedes crear variables dinámicamente con `eval()` aunque es **muy poco recomendable,** también se puede con $$

```
<?php

  $x = 'variable1';
  $$x = '2';  // doble signo $ 
  echo $variable1;
```

Aunque posiblemente lo mejor sea usar arrays

```
$nombres = array();
while( .... )
{
   $nombres[] = $nuevo_nombre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Crear dinámicamente variables
$datos = array('a' => 'uno', 'b' => 'dos', 'c' => 'tres', 'd'=> 'cuatro');

/*$$ crea una variable con el mismo nombre del $campo del array le asigna $valor a la variable  */

foreach ($datos as $campo=>$valor) {
           $$campo = $valor;
 }
 echo $a;
 echo $b;
 echo $c;
 echo $d;
```