# ¿Asignar un nombre a un $row?

Tags: php

Tengo ésta función:

```
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["name"]);
```

Lo cual muestra el dato de X usuario cuyo valor esté en las respectivas tablas, id y name.

Pero sólo muestra el dato y ya, lo que quiero hacer es asignarle un nombre a cada dato.

Por ejemplo:

ID: **Muestra la ID del usuario (id)**
Nombre: **Muestra el nombre del usuario (name)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$enlace = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pw", "db");

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$nick = urlencode($_GET['nick']);
$consulta = "SELECT id, name FROM player WHERE name='".$nick."'";

if ($resultado = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta)) {

    /* obtener array asociativo */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["name"]);
    }

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
}

/* cerrar la conexión */
mysqli_close($link);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Tengo ese código, pero al ejecutarlo, me muestra automáticamente el valor del usuario con respecto a cada tabla (id, name). Y no quiero eso, quiero que diga.

ID: **id del usuario (en este caso, el valor asignado en id.**

Nombre: **nombre del usuario (el nombre asignado en name**

Comment: @aldanux Edité mi pregunta agregando más información.

Comment: He borrado todo ya que no me queda claro, como se ve...

Comment: Último intento: Lo que quieres es realmente darle formato en el momento cuando recibes los valores....? Ve a [ver el ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45f7e4a85c1ebe8d0d899dfa55cd97a66531c0e6) y me dices si he acertado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si lo que quieres hacer es algo como esto:

```
    /* obtener array asociativo */

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

    $id   = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", "ID: " + $id, " Nombre: " + $name]);
}
```

o quieres crear variables dinámicamente para poder utilizarlas fuera del bucle, en este caso mira este hilo: [¿Cómo crear dinámicamente variables dentro de un while?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3161/c%C3%B3mo-crear-din%C3%A1micamente-variables-dentro-de-un-while)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es que devuelva el nombre de la columna más el valor.

Esto lo tienes que especificar en el while por ejemplo así:

```
/* obtener array asociativo */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        echo "ID: " . $row["id"] . "<br>";
        echo "Nombre: " . $row["name"] . "<br>";

    }
```

Con esto defines al principio del valor a qué se refiere cada campo.

Por último veo que tu código es vulnerable a inyección sql. Te dejo el siguiente enlace donde se explica cómo evitarlo: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Gracias por el consejo amigo!