# Ayuda separando valores y asignarlos a una variable usando MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql, php7

Saludos tengo el siguiente caso:
 Poseo esta tabla:
`id    monto     afiliacion
1       10        BASICO
2       20        AVANZADO
3       30        PREMIUN`
Mi query es este:

```
 $plan = "SELECT monto, afiliacion FROM monto_mensualidad";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $plan);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
      // $monto = $row['monto'];
      // $afiliacion = $row['afiliacion'];
      // echo $monto;
      $b = $row[0];
      $a = $row[1];

      echo $a .' ' . $b;
    }
```

me ocupa el asignarle a un grupo de variables logicamente seriadas pero que mas o menos tengan el siguiente esquema:
`$plan_a_monto     = "10";
$plan_a_afiliacion = "BASICO";`
Y así sucesivamente con todos los datos que existen en la tabla.
Si  debo yo de colocarle los numeros de las posiciones no tengo problema ya que no son muchas filas son apenas 3 y solo 2 columnas pero me he fundido tratando de hacerlo..!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias crear variables asi:

```
${"nombre"} = contenido
```

Por tanto prueba esto:

```
$plan = "SELECT id, monto, afiliacion FROM monto_mensualidad";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $plan);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
      $id = $row["id"];
      $monto = $row['monto'];
      $afiliacion = $row['afiliacion'];
      ${"plan_".$id} = array("monto"=>$monto, "afiliacion"=>$afiliacion);
    }
```

eso crearia las siguientes variables:

```
$plan_1 = array("monto"=10, "afiliacion"="basico")

$plan_2 = array("monto"=20, "afiliacion"="avanzado")

$plan_3 = array("monto"=30, "afiliacion"="premium")
```

Puedes cambiar la concatenacion en `${"plan_".$id}` por cualquier otra variable, de esta forma es mas practico, no tendrias 2 variables por plan sino un arreglo, y si quieres a, b y c, has esto:

```
$letras = array("a", "b", "c");
```

y luego dentro del while

```
${"plan_".$letra[$id-1]}
```

y si quieres que sean dos variables:

```
${"plan_".$id."_monto"}
${"plan_".$id."_afiliacion"}
```

y les asignas sus valores.

te invito a pasar por este link:

**Documentación:**

http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php

**Pregunta que explica la variable variable:**

[¿Cómo crear dinámicamente variables dentro de un while?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3161/c%C3%B3mo-crear-din%C3%A1micamente-variables-dentro-de-un-while)

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, si yo llegue en mi busqueda al link que me indicastes pero me ha costado un poco comprender el manejo de la variables dinamicas, poco a poco voy...! en tu sugerencia voy a colocar la correccion de la variable `$id` pero me fue super util para comprender y lograr implementarlo en mi codigo.. Gracias..!